# import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "next-auth/client" doesnt work in _app.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGhekiErHso&lc=UgxYeO4X60SBiKSTYyp4AaABAg.9WmWFhab7UX9WmzTutWP_V, at the 39 min of the video you can see the authentication part in `_app.js`.

When I `import { Provider as AuthProvider }  from "next-auth/client"` I got the below error:

> Module not found: Package path ./client is not exported from package
> C:\Users\saeed\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs\node_modules\next-auth
> (see exports field in
> C:\Users\saeed\Amazon-starter-template-nextjs\node_modules\next-auth\package.json)

If I change it to: `import { Provider as AuthProvider } from "next-auth/react";` I got this error:

> Server Error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
> the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
> imports.

Comment: Yes, you should change the import to `next-auth/react` when using `next-auth` v4. For the second error make sure you're exporting all your React components correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your import. Provider was renamed to SessionProvider on v4.0.

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
```

You no longer have to use an alias, since Provider was renamed.
`next-auth/client` is deprecated,  use `next-auth/react` instead.

The next steps on the tutorial are also outdated. The useSession hook has been updated to return an object.

Instead of using `const [session] = useSession()`, it should be `const { data: session } = useSession();`

After that, you can easily access `session.user.name`

Answer (score 0):

`next-auth/react` is correct, `/client` is [deprecated](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#next-authreact)

The follow-up error looks like you're not exporting your function/component, are you missing the export in your file? e.g.

```
export default MyApp
```

Comment: In the end of the script of _app.js it exist: export default MyApp

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change your import like below. The provider was renamed to SessionProvider on v4.0.

```
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
```

Second, you should change the _app.js codes like this:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

Finally use this code to use your session:

```
const { data: session } = useSession();

// use this code for print your data

session.user.name
```